# How to read-write properties changes at reusing QML components

Tags: qt, qml

I` ve got such component as QMLDoubleEdit

```
import QtQuick 1.1
Item{
property double dVal: 0;
Rectangle {

    TextInput {
        id: textDVal
        focus:true
        validator:DoubleValidator{
            bottom:0;
            top:200;
            decimals: 3
        }           
        text: dVal           
    }
}
```

}

When it used to implement UI in for example

```
Item{
property double dWesMax:    0;
property double dWesMin:    0;


Rectangle {       
    QMLDoubleEdit {
        id: edtMaxWes
        x: 40
        y: 50
        dVal: dWesMax
    }

    QMLDoubleEdit {
        id: edtMinWes
        x: 260
        y: 50
        dVal: dWesMin
    }
 }
 }
```

I can set it initial values from my *.cpp code, but i can`t read them after changing:

// that is ok

```
QDeclarativeContext *context=m_qmlFrmParam->rootContext();
    context->setContextProperty("dWesMax",m_wntModule->getWesMax());
```

// that is not

```
double dVal=0;
dVal=(m_dlgRoot->property("dWesMax")).toDouble();
```

Better explain here:
1) Creating UI

```
void frmWesParam::prepareElements(){
m_qmlFrmParam=new QDeclarativeView();
m_qmlFrmParam->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/view/wesparams/QMLBgPanel.qml"));
m_qmlFrmParam->setResizeMode(QDeclarativeView::SizeRootObjectToView);
m_dlgRoot=m_qmlFrmParam->rootObject();
QDeclarativeContext *context=m_qmlFrmParam->rootContext();
context->setContextProperty("viewerWidget",this);
}

void frmWesParam::setWesMax(double dVal){
m_dlgRoot->setProperty("dWesMax",QString::number(dVal));
}
```

2) Showing it (just row of elements QMLDoubleEdit, and two buttons - "Ok","Cancel" onPress, emiting  accept or cancel)

```
frmWesParam *vw=new frmWesParam();
vw->setWesMax(14.3);
vw->show();
```

3) When widget appears, it contain my value - 14.3.
 Here user can change it, and push button;
4) On signal accept i got

```
void frmWesParam::catchAccept(){
if(m_wntModule!=0){
double dVal=0;
dVal=(m_dlgRoot->property("dWesMax")).toDouble();
qDebug()<<dVal;
}
```

And here i got only what i sat    setWesMax(...) .

Comment: What's `m_dlgRoot`? Isn't the context property you're setting in C++ different from the one in the QML code? Properties that you set using `setContextProperty` can be read using `contextProperty` member function of the same context.

Comment: Ye, this is so, but i change value in QMLDoubleEdit, but can`t read;

Comment: m_qmlFrmParam=new QDeclarativeView();
    ....
    m_dlgRoot=m_qmlFrmParam->rootObject();

Comment: What do you mean can't read? Are you getting initial value or invalid QVariant?

Comment: i`ve got values that i set there by setContext()

Comment: And how are you changing the value? In the QMLDoubleEdit? If so, you're not changing it at all, since your bindings only work in one direction. When you change the value in QMLDoubleEdit, dVal doesn't get updated.

Comment: I change value in QMLDoubleEdit, then i`ve got button(qml) that sends

Comment: accept() - this signal i catch and after that try to use dVal;

Comment: I'm sorry, but can't expect help if you provide just shreds of relevant information. Please post full piece code showing what you're trying to achieve and where you're not getting results you're expecting.

Comment: i changed my question, with some code to clear up what i do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in comments, changing values in `TextInput` does not change the `dWesMax` property. You should either read the `text` property of `TextInput` in C++, or have QML update `dWesMax` upon change in `TextInput`. Here's an example of how you could do it:

**QMLDoubleEdit**

```
import QtQuick 1.1
Item{
property double dVal: 0;
property var textChangedCb: null;
Rectangle {

    TextInput {
        id: textDVal
        focus:true
        validator:DoubleValidator{
            bottom:0;
            top:200;
            decimals: 3
        }           
        text: dVal
        onTextChanged: {dVal = text; if (textChangedCb) textChangedCb();}
    }
}
```

**UI code**

```
Item{
property double dWesMax:    0;
property double dWesMin:    0;


Rectangle {       
    QMLDoubleEdit {
        id: edtMaxWes
        x: 40
        y: 50
        dVal: dWesMax
        textChangedCb: {dWesMax = dVal;}
    }

    QMLDoubleEdit {
        id: edtMinWes
        x: 260
        y: 50
        dVal: dWesMin
        textChangedCb: {dWesMin = dVal;}
    }
 }
}
```

This is not the cleanest way to do it, but it will work without changing your C++ code and QML structure.

Comment: I got conceptual idea, thanks. After some correct i`ll post piece of working code

Answer (score 0):

i`ve got annother solution based on help by W.B.

UI:

```
Item{
 property alias dWesMax:    edtMaxWes.dVal;
 property alias dWesMin:    edtMinWes.dVal;


 Rectangle {       
 QMLDoubleEdit {
     id: edtMaxWes
     x: 40
     y: 50
 }

 QMLDoubleEdit {
    id: edtMinWes
    x: 260
    y: 50
 }
}
}
```

QMLDoubleEdit:

```
Item{
 property double dVal: 0;

 Rectangle {
    TextInput {
        id: textDVal
        validator:DoubleValidator{
            bottom:0;
            top:200;
            decimals: 3
        }
        onTextChanged: {
            if(text.length>0){
              dVal=parseFloat(text);
            }
        }

    }
}
}
```