# QML does not write to C++ property when bound to component and component value changes

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt6

I'm working on a QML project. In the UI I'm working on, I need to  both update slider from C++ and read the current value into C++ from QML. Properties seems to be the right solution. So far I've read different questions on SO without success [Two way binding C++ model in QML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41232999/two-way-binding-c-model-in-qml), [Changed Properties do not trigger signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25381224/how-to-read-write-properties-changes-at-reusing-qml-components), etc... In my current code I declared a property in my C++ class

```cpp
class MyClass : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyClass(QObject*);
    Q_PROPERTY(double myValue READ getMyValue WRITE setMyValue NOTIFY myValueChanged)

    void setMyValue(double n) {
        std::cerr << "myValue  being update: " << n << "\n";
        myValue = n;
    }

    double myValue = 30;
...
}
```

And exposed it into Qt via a singleton

```cpp
qmlRegisterSingletonInstance("com.me.test", 1, 0, "MyClass", &myClass);
```

Then bound the C++ property to a QML slider

```
import com.me.test
ApplicationWindow {
    Slider {
        id: slider
        height: 30
        width: 100
        from: 0
        to: 100
        value: myClass.myValue
        onValueChanged {
            console.log("value = " + value)
            console.log("myClass.myValue = " + myClass.myValue)
        }

        /* Doesn't help
        Binding {
            target: slider
            property: "value"
            value: myClass.myValue
        }*/
    }
}
```

The binding seems to work. I can modify the value of `myValue` then emit `myValueChanged` to make QML update it's slider. But given that `myClass.myValue` is bounded to `slider.value`. I'd assume both values gets updated at the same time. But dragging the slider shows that they have different values. The following it what is printed in the console when I drag my slider.

```
qml: value = 19.863013698630137
qml: myClass.myValue = 30
```

Furthermore `setMyValue` seems to not being called unless an explicit assignment is made like `myClass.myValue = 0`. I also tried the Binding component without success. Why is this the case and could I make the C++ property updated whenever i drag the slider?

Qt: 6.2.1
Compiler: clang/gcc
OS: Windows/Linux

Update: tested a reverse binding. Still printing the same result

```
import com.me.test
ApplicationWindow {
    Slider {
        id: slider
        height: 30
        width: 100
        from: 0
        to: 100
        value: myClass.myValue
        onValueChanged {
            console.log("value = " + value)
            console.log("myClass.myValue = " + myClass.myValue)
        }
        Binding {
            target: myClass
            property: "myValue"
            value: slider.value
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You bind `value` to `myClass.myValue` but not vice versa. I mean when you bind A to B that doesn't create implicit bindings B to A. Otherwise, you know, If that were the case so changing A will notify B that, in turn, will notify A and so on indefinitely. On the other hand when you bind A to B so A should be notified when the B changes and the set A manually it will break the bindings.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the signal when modifying the value:

```
Q_PROPERTY(double myValue READ getMyValue WRITE setMyValue NOTIFY myValueChanged)
```

This means that you **promise** you'll send the `myValueChanged` signal whenever the C++ code changes the value. So the following should work:

```
void setMyValue(double n) {
    std::cerr << "myValue  being update: " << n << "\n";
    myValue = n;
    emit(myValueChanged());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To update C++ property from QML, you can use `Binding`:

```
import com.me.test
ApplicationWindow {
    Slider {
        id: slider
        height: 30
        width: 100
        from: 0
        to: 100
        value: myClass.myValue
        onValueChanged {
            console.log("value = " + value)
            console.log("myClass.myValue = " + myClass.myValue)
        }
         // C++ property was bounded to QML above, now we should bind QML to C++
        Binding {
            target: myClass 
            property: "myValue"
            value: slider.value
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens when `myClass.myValue` will be updated and will fire its `myValueChanged`?

Comment: @folibis It will update the slider value' property. Of course, the `setMyValue` method should start with comparison between a new value and the current value, and emit `myValueChanged` only if the value was really updated. In other case, you could see a binding loop

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the suggested solution. But still not seeing the setter called nor the value of `console.log("myClass.myValue = " + myClass.myValue)` changed.

Comment: @MaryChang In the above code, you will see `console.log("myClass.myValue = " + myClass.myValue)` when you will move a slider. To see `myClass.myValue` value changed, have a look at [Connections](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-connections.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal working example of two way updating Slider:

**main.cpp:**

```
data dataObj;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("dataCpp", (QObject*)&dataObj);
```

**data.h:**

```
class data : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int value READ value WRITE setValue NOTIFY valueChanged)
public:
    explicit data(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    int value(void);
    void setValue(int new_value);
public slots:
    void reset(void);
signals:
    void valueChanged();
private:
    int dataValue;
};
```

**data.cpp:**

```
data::data(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    dataValue = 250;
}

int data::value()
{
    return dataValue;
}

void data::setValue(int new_value)
{
    if(dataValue != new_value)
    {
        qDebug() << "setting" << new_value;
        dataValue = new_value;
        emit valueChanged();
    }
}

void data::reset()
{
    if(dataValue != 0)
    {
        qDebug() << "resetting to 0";
        dataValue = 0;
        emit valueChanged();
    }
}
```

**main.qml:**

```
Slider {
    id: slider
    height: 50
    width: 500
    from: 0
    to: 500
    live: false
    value: dataCpp.value
    onValueChanged: dataCpp.value = value
}

Button{
    anchors.top: slider.bottom
    text: "Reset"
    onPressed: dataCpp.reset()
}
```